# javascript : finding the exact position of user confirmation alert in browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to create a tutorial for a web page which includes a pointer, pointing to the geolocation alert . as you know this kind of alerts are shown by the browser and not from the page itself which makes it impossible (as far as i know) to get the position of their window using only javascript. but i want my pointer to point to exactly the allow button of this pop up window . how can i do this ? i want a solution to work cross screens . if i set the flash position using say "pixel" it will not work for a different screen .

what is the best solution for this problem ?!

i want something like this picture but works cross screens :

[image]

Regards,
Mohammad

Comment: The position won't change whatever the screen ... it is align to left.

Comment: I think your main problem here is that the alert, is browser dependent.  So even if you tested with every known browser today, and got it working now.  In the future they might change there mind, and it's done differently.

Comment: i know its align to left . but say if i set "margin-left: 100px" for example . it will be different in another screen and the pointer would not be correct anymore . the same is true for grid view .